# Nginx Won't start after GitLab Update

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, gitlab

I tried updating GitLab by running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gitlab-ce`. Everything seemed fine during the install, but after it finished, nginx stopped working and I can't get it to start.

After running: `sudo gitlab-ctl status`, I get this:

```
run: gitlab-workhorse: (pid 4378) 8613s; run: log: (pid 937) 9953s
run: logrotate: (pid 19116) 1412s; run: log: (pid 933) 9953s
down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 943) 9953s
run: postgresql: (pid 4456) 8581s; run: log: (pid 939) 9953s
run: redis: (pid 4466) 8581s; run: log: (pid 935) 9953s
run: sidekiq: (pid 4474) 8578s; run: log: (pid 940) 9953s
run: unicorn: (pid 4496) 8576s; run: log: (pid 931) 9953s
```

I tried running `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` and rebooting. That didn't help. I also tried `sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`, which gave me this:

`timeout: down: nginx: 0s, normally up, want up`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind! Was able to get nginx to start by changing the permissions of /var/opt/gitlab to 755.

Comment: Also, for anyone else, make sure to `sudo chmod 700 /etc/gitlab/ssl` if you're using SSL.

Comment: The above worked for me,  perhaps add it as an answer and mark the question complete?

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
sudo gitlab-ctl tail
```

to view all errors.

I made a silly mistake of not creating certificates for the GitLab registry subdomain on my previous edit to my GitLab instance.